# Differentiate an integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If I want to differentiate the following integral $$F(x,y)=\int_0^x u(t,y)\,dt$$ with respect to the variable y, I get $$F_y(x,y)=\int_0^x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(t,y)\,dt$$ What about if I differentiate with respect to $x$? Does it become $0$ ? I'm asking because I see the $x$ at the limit of integration and I'm getting a little confused.

Comment: Your function $F$ is a function of both $y$ and $x$.

Comment: So if I want to calculate $\cfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(y)$ how would it look like?

Comment: Your differentiation is a partial differentiation wrt $y$.

Comment: if $u(t,y)$ is continuous in $t$ then $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x} = u(x,y)$. This is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The FTC says that if $f$ is continuous, and $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt,$ then $F'(x)=f(x).$